# Is it possible to expand geom_ribbon to xlimits?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code (as an example) which I would like to adapt such that the ribbon extends to the entire xrange, as `geom_hline()` does. The ribbon indicates what values are within accepted bounds. In my real application  sometimes has no upper or lower bound, so the hline by itself is not enough to determine whether values are within bounds.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2016-12-19)
dates <- seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'), as.Date('2016-12-31'), by = 1)
values <- rexp(length(dates), 1)
groups <- rpois(length(dates), 5)
temp <- data.frame(
    date = dates,
    value = values,
    group = groups,
    value.min = 0,
    value.max = 2
)
ggplot(temp, aes(date, value)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value.min, ymax = value.max), fill = '#00cc33', alpha = 0.6) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value.min)) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value.max)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~group)
```

I tried setting the `x` in `geom_ribbon` to `dates`as well, but then only fractions of the range are filled.
Also I tried this:

```r
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = -Inf, ymax = 2, x = dates), data = data.frame(), fill = '#00cc33', alpha = 0.6)
```

but then the data seems to be overwritten for the entire plot and I get the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'value' not found`. Even if it would work then the range is still actually too narrow as the xlimits are expanded.

Comment: The error message "object 'value' not found" tells you that ggplot cannot find the variable `value`, which you mapped to y in your global aesthetic mappings, in the empty data frame that you specified in `data = data.frame()`.

Comment: I understand it would not find the `value` within the `geom_ribbon`, but I added `data = data.frame()` hoping to decouple it from the inherited data. However, it backfires by decoupling the data entirely which seems odd to me.

Comment: you can use `inherit.aes=FALSE` argument to decouple it.

Comment: You also really don't need 336 copies of each horizontal line: `geom_hline(data=data.frame(), yintercept = c(temp$value.min[1], temp$value.max[1]))` shld suffice

Comment: I don't really need the hline at all, I added them mostly to clarify what I want the ribbon to look like. Thanks for pointing out the lines are duplicated, actually 366 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
ggplot(temp, aes(as.numeric(date), value)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin = value.min, ymax = value.max), temp[!duplicated(temp$group),], fill = '#00cc33', alpha = 0.6) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value.min)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = value.max)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x, origin = "1970-01-01"), "%b %y")) + 
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

Note  that I used `as.numeric(date)`, because otherwise `Inf` and `-Inf` yield

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

To get date labels for numeric values, I adjusted the `scale_x_continuous` labels accordingly. (Although they are not exact here. You may want to adjust it by using the exact dates instead of month/year, or alternatively set manual breaks using the `breaks` argument and for example `seq.Date`.)

Also note that I used `temp[!duplicated(temp$group),]` to avoid overplotting and thus maintaining the desired alpha transparency.

Comment: FWIW OP prbly doesn't really need 336 copies of each horizontal line marker despite what they have in their example code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on lukeA's answer I produced the following code, which I think is a little simpler:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2016-12-19)
dates <- seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'), as.Date('2016-12-31'), by = 1)
values <- rexp(length(dates), 1)
groups <- rpois(length(dates), 5)
temp <- data.frame(
    date = dates,
    value = values,
    group = groups,
    value.min = 1,
    value.max = 2
)
bounds <- data.frame(
    xmin = -Inf,
    xmax = Inf,
    ymin = temp$value.min[1],
    ymax = temp$value.max[1]
)
ggplot(temp, aes(date, value)) +
    geom_rect(
        aes(
            xmin = as.Date(xmin, origin = '1970-01-01'),
            xmax = as.Date(xmax, origin = '1970-01-01'),
            ymin = ymin,
            ymax = ymax
        ),
        data = bounds,
        fill = '#00cc33',
        alpha = 0.3,
        inherit.aes = FALSE
    ) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~group)
```

I created a temporary dataframe containing the bounds for the rectangle, and added `inherit.aes = FALSE` since apparently the bounds otherwise overrule the `temp` data.frame (still seems a bug to me). By transforming the `-Inf` and `Inf` to the correct datatype I didn't need the custom labeler (if your dealing with `POSIXt` use the correct `as.POSIXct/lt` as automatic transformation fails).

Comment: Interesting, I though I had tried `as.Date(Inf, origin="1970-01-01")`.